# E&R Usage Graphs

Tags: discussion

I'm using the E&R API to collect usage stats and graph the data. Here is what I'm come up with so far. It's only been running for a couple of days, so not much data yet... I'll update in a couple of days with more data. Also, the times are GMT as I'm in the UK!

Does any body have any ideas of other ways to visualise this data?

### **Graphs Updated: 16/02/11 18:20 GMT - last 4 weeks**

Note: I think there is something strange going on with the API stats data for users!

[image: Questions Per Day]
[image: Answers Per Day]
[image: Comments Per Day]
[image: Votes Per Day]
[image: Badges Per Day]
[image: New Users Per Day]

Comment: *Neat-o!* Can you link to the E&R API documentation?

Comment: @tyblu: http://api.electronics.stackexchange.com/1.0/help

Comment: How did the number of users per day drop below 0 in Sat 22 (and the 15 too)?

Comment: @wallacoloo: I'm not sure, it graphs the number of users at a point in time less the number of users exactly 24 hrs earlier. The only way this can happen if there are fewer users than the day before. Something weird is going on with the API, the graph shows that it dropped vertically by 10 users at midnight, and then jumps back up exactly 24 hrs later. This looks a bit suspect to me. My program also logs the actual data received by the API, when I get some time I'll look at that and work out what's going on.

Comment: @BG100 - Care to post an update?  We're at 12 questions/day according to Area51; I'm curious to see if that's sustained or not.

Comment: @reemrevnivek: Done.

Comment: @BG100 - Can we have one more, to analyze the effects of the launch?  Or did that break your script?

Answer (score 3):

Hey, this is very cool!

If you can generalize it a bit, it could be used to generate a dashboard for any Stack Exchange site.

I also recommend listing your code as an app on http://stackapps.com so more people can find it!

see:
https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-here

Comment: Thanks, that was kinda my intention anyway, but I'm a long way off publishing the code as this was just quickly thrown together. The dashboard is a good idea, although I have nowhere to host it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Very cool, nice work. How about some statistical / analytical views? I'm thinking histograms that show usage patterns by day-of-week, month-of-year. Trend views would also be interesting, like rate of growth in the number of users for example...